# Reg: count data from mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Using below query to get counts:

```
  db.agent.aggregate([
{ $match: {"$and": [{"eventId":{"$in": ["IP200","LAS201","LAS207","LAS201"]}},{"Uid":
   { "$in": db.agent.distinct("Uid",{"$and": [{"agentRole": {"$in": ["SW_TECH","SE_TECH","SF_TECH","MW_TECH"]}},
   {"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-05-13T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-05-13T23:59:59.999-0400")}} ]}) }
    },{"timeStamp": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-05-13T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-05-13T23:59:59.999-0400")}}]}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timeStamp" }}, User: "$Uid" } , JOBCOUNT: {$addToSet: "$jobId"}}},
{ $project: {  "_id" : NumberInt(0),  "Uid" : "$_id.User", "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "TotalJOB" : {$size:"$JOBCOUNT"} }}, 
])
```

it;s displaying records 50 per  page in outptu, but we need only total count to display how can we achieve it.

Comment: provide soe sample data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to count how many documents are there in the last stage of the pipeline.

Just add a $count stage, for e.g.

```
  db.agent.aggregate([
{ $match: {"$and": [{"eventId":{"$in": ["IP200","LAS201","LAS207","LAS201"]}},{"Uid":
   { "$in": db.agent.distinct("Uid",{"$and": [{"agentRole": {"$in": ["SW_TECH","SE_TECH","SF_TECH","MW_TECH"]}},
   {"loginLogoutTime":{"$gte": ISODate("2020-05-13T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-05-13T23:59:59.999-0400")}} ]}) }
    },{"timeStamp": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-05-13T00:00:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-05-13T23:59:59.999-0400")}}]}},
{ $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$timeStamp" }}, User: "$Uid" } , JOBCOUNT: {$addToSet: "$jobId"}}},
{ $project: {  "_id" : NumberInt(0),  "Uid" : "$_id.User", "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "TotalJOB" : {$size:"$JOBCOUNT"} }}, 
{ $count: "Uid" }
])
```